# Trying to download "Hello world" using JS and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, pdf, fpdf

I'm trying to download a pdf when i click a link.

These are my codes:

```
function issue_bill(order_id){
$.post('orders/issueBilll?id_order='+order_id,
        order_id,
        function()
        {
          $('example').replaceWith('Bill issued');
        }
      );
}


public function executeIssueBill(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  $pdf=new FPDF();
  $pdf->AddPage();
  $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
  $pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
  $pdf->Output();
}
```

When i click on the link, it doesn't download the pdf document. If i go the inspector of Firebug i get this below in the "Response" section of the Console:

```
%PDF-1.3
3 0 obj
<</Type /Page
/Parent 1 0 R
/Resources 2 0 R
/Contents 4 0 R>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Filter /FlateDecode /Length 72>>
stream
x�3R��2�35W(�r
Q�w3T04�30PISp
    �Z*�[����(hx����+���(j*�d��
endstream
endobj
1 0 obj
<</Type /Pages
/Kids [3 0 R ]
/Count 1
/MediaBox [0 0 595.28 841.89]
>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<</Type /Font
/BaseFont /Helvetica-Bold
/Subtype /Type1
/Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<<
/ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]
/Font <<
/F1 5 0 R
>>
/XObject <<
>>
>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<<
/Producer (FPDF 1.53)
/CreationDate (D:20110126103602)
>>
endobj
7 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Pages 1 0 R
/OpenAction [3 0 R /FitH null]
/PageLayout /OneColumn
>>
endobj
xref
0 8
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000228 00000 n 
0000000416 00000 n 
0000000009 00000 n 
0000000087 00000 n 
0000000315 00000 n 
0000000520 00000 n 
0000000596 00000 n 
trailer
<<
/Size 8
/Root 7 0 R
/Info 6 0 R
>>
startxref
699
%%EOF
```

What should i do to download the document? I don't have any problem to download the pdf if i call directly `issueBill()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to make an AJAX request, where the response is stored in a JavaScript variable, you want to make a normal HTTP request -- the kind made when someone clicks a link or types a URL in the browser address bar.

Send the user to the URL of your PDF generator with `window.location` in JavaScript.

If you want to try to trick the browser into staying on your page while it does it, make the request by creating an iframe pointing to the URL of your PDF generator. You'll also have to fudge the content-type header to NOT tell the browser it's a PDF, otherwise it might attempt to display it in the window instead of forcing a download.

Comment: Exactly like that. Note that you will stay on current page if you select the 'download' option in FPDF::Output()

Comment: Thanks Dan, anyway, why do you think I don't want to make an AJAX request?? In the way you say, I'm reloading the page, but..maybe I don't want to reload the page..So..does it would be possible using AJAX, or does it just be not advisable/useless?

Comment: It's not possible, not advisable and useless. You're not reloading the page either.