# Trying to use window.location and replaceWith() in the same time

Tags: php, javascript

I have a link that when clicked should generate a PDF document and change the text of himself.

This is my JS function:

```
function clander(){

  window.location="orders/issueBill/order_id/"+order_id;

  $('#jander').replaceWith('pdf just generated');

}
```

The link:

```
<a href="#" id="jander" onClick='clander()'>click here</a>
```

The action:

```
public function executeIssueBill(sfWebRequest $request) {

//here is the code that generates the pdf.

}
```

The problem: when I click the link, it generates the pdf but the text of the link is not changed. It only changes the text if I remove the `window.location...` line.

The reason of my code is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803191/fpdf-trying-to-download-hello-world-using-js-and-php).

Any idea?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that it never gets to this part:

```
$('#jander').replaceWith('pdf just generated');
```

It redirects the user to `"orders/issueBill/order_id/"+order_id`, which is a different page, so it doesn't remember state.

I guess your best bet is to pass a parameter to the new page (ie. `"orders/issueBill/order_id/"+order_id+"?pdf_generated=1"`) - this way it'll know that the pdf was generated, and you can change the link accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the order of your statements in the js function. If you change the order the other way around, should work fine like so:

```
<script>

function clander(){

    document.getElementById('jander').innerHTML = 'pdf just generated';
    window.location="orders/issueBill/order_id/"+order_id;

}

</script>

<a href="#" id="jander" onClick='clander()'>click here</a>
```

Best,
Kamran

Comment: No, that won't. As soon as it gets changed, it will then redirect and that change will be lost.

Comment: hi xil3, I tested the code and it works fine for me. It does change the text as the original poster asked and then moves on to the next statement. If the next statement points to a download-able file, things would work nicely! e.g. window.location = "demo.zip";

Comment: or for that matter, you can have the window.location to point to a server script that responds with an appropriate header to download the file. e.g. window.location = 'foo.aspx'; // foo.aspx responds with http headers to download the target / requested file

Comment: Yea, if it doesn't leave the page it would work, but if it redirects to another page it would not. If it's a file that it redirects to then I guess it would work, but that wasn't made perfectly clear in the question.